# .font(.system(size:17)) - Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an error with font size, what does it mean?

```
 Button(action:{
                    },label: {
                        Text("Get Started")
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                            .font(.system(size:17))
```

> .font(.system(size:17)) - Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

```
                            .padding(.horizontal, 68)
                            .padding(.vertical,15.5)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(Color(hue: 0.992, saturation: 0.623, brightness: 0.956))
                            .frame(width: nil)
                            .cornerRadius(19)
                            .padding(.top, 480)

                    })
```

Comment: @TamásSengel But  Type 'UIFont' has no member 'system'

Comment: I see no issues. Please provide more code.

Comment: Tested with Xcode 11.2 - works. I assume it is compiler mistake due to complex view structure. Try to break your view hierarchy apart into smaller blocks it would help you to see the real place of error... and it is good practice in general.

Answer (score -1):

`UIFont` has no member `system`.
You could use `.systemFont(ofSize: 17)` instead.